# Redis StackExchange Client - Frequently receiving "Timeout exceptions", "Redis connection exception", "No connection available to service"

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am frequently getting the below mentioned errors, the dll version used in the project is - 1.0.488.0

System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing GET

StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: GET

No connection is available to service this operation: EXISTS

Can anyone help me out in figuring what the issue can be?

Have also created an issue on StackExchange's Github repo for the same
[Issue created on Github for the same](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/659)

Comment: is redis server online? can you connect using redis-cli? is the IP correctly configured? (localhost or remote ip?)

Comment: Yes its online, i can connect and do all operations properly. These error logs form randomly. Its a separate DB server and the application code resides on an app server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your connection broke. And when it did, any commands already sent to Redis would have timed out on the client application, even though they could have executed on the server. If you upgrade to a later version of the StackExchange.Redis client, you will get richer diagnostics information about what the state of the threadpool, CPU etc was on the client application side.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Carl. Will upgrade to the latest version of the client dll and check once again.